# Future in mathematics

Tags: undergraduate-education, student-motivation, africa

My sibling is done with high school and has always scored A in Maths and am not in position to advise her on the future in line of her niche.

She's not yet in university and she's in her vacation but I hope that by societies, she can get inspiration from like-minds through engagement and interaction to achieve greater (she's a big dreamer.) she currently has little career guidance other than her love for numbers.

Are there any societies to join or courses to take that would be good for them?

The location is Uganda, Kampala.

Comment: On a possibly useful note, the branch of the [African Institute for Mathematical Sciences](https://aims.ac.rw) in Kigali might have some web resources to suggest.  Getting a bachelor's or Honours in mathematics might be good.

Comment: Is she currently pursuing her studies, user18858, whether through self-study, or at a college/university?  (Specify which, if either.)  As stated, the question is rather vague, because recommendations for further (post-secondary) study, or self-study, or societies to join, and such may very considerably depending on your sibling's current activities.  Of course, input from your sibling would be advantageous as well.  Does she want to pursue studies in math?  If so, what area(s) does she love most?

Comment: @Namaste she's not yet in university and she's in her vacation but I hope that by societies, she can get inspiration from like-minds through engagement and interaction to achieve greater (she's a big dreamer.) she currently has little career guidance other than her love for numbers. Thanks

Comment: @Tommi Brander the courses and societies should be for grooming her into a finer Mathematician and inspire her further through interaction and affection (currently she has little guidance) with like-minds.

Comment: You should edit those details into the question - link at the bottom of the question or here: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/posts/15449/edit

Comment: @user18858  Does your sister have access to the internet?  That's a great resource to connect with folks globally, in areas of mathematics that she loves most (you speak of "her love for numbers" - so number theory comes to mind.)  She can use math.stackexchange.com as a resource in further independent study in areas in which she's interested; also, she might like the site "The Art of Problem Solving", e.g., which caters to very bright students, usually pre-university.

Answer (score 3):

(Sticking my lion claw in.)

User18858:  That is great about your sister.  I just want to give you a slight caution.  The vast majority of people who "like math" or "do well at math" go on to work in fields OTHER than straight mathematics.  There are many opportunities to use skill in math in engineering, business, etc.

If you listen to advice here, you are apt to get a blind spot to this since the vast majority of people here are teachers of mathematics (and even while teaching service classes), tend to ignore the statistics of their students.  It is not meant unkindly, but it is still a blind spot that many have.

Comment: Even if she doesn't plan to major in mathematics, e.g., chooses to pursue stats, engineering, computing, it nonetheless makes sense to explore mathematical interests, whether it be applied mathematics, as all the options you list certainly need more education in mathematics than what one obtains at the high-school level.  I'd encourage her to explore her interests, where they can be applied, and to stay connected (even if only via the internet) with other folks in her position.

Comment: So I think the advice here is perfectly appropriate, whatever career field she pursues; there are many avenues open to those who "like math" and are "good at math" (engineering, accounting/actuarial work, cryptography, etc.) but virtually all of them require a university education and additional courses in mathematics. It behooves her to explore her interest and explore areas (and possible careers) relying on what she most loves in mathematics.

Comment: I somewhat agree with your comments, but this is probably something that belongs as a comment (maybe have to extend it to two consecutive comments if the character count is too high for one comment) rather than as an answer.

Comment: OTOH (re blind spot) a good teacher should be ready to take a student wherever the student leads.  (But somehow the internet does not always bring out what is good in people -- e.g. currently 3 DV on this sincere but slightly OT question.)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably impossible for you to completely figure out what it really is that's going to make her happy and the best you can do is get some idea of it. If she could find a way to figure out more about her true feelings, she might get a better idea of it and then if this question explained it better, I might be able to get a good idea of what will suit her. If she has the brain that won't resist it too strongly, what might work best is for her to just keep doing what ever she feels like doing right then and not work so hard to make her future go a certain way because she will be happier if she can naturally live in the moment and have no to do lists and not work so hard to keep doors open to certain things for later and learn how to quickly adapt to what ever the choices are after she burns her bridges. I don't know what will work.